# the best way to design a cross platform app

Tags: android, ios, html, web

What is the best solution to make a mobile app for both android and iOS?

-i need a light size app 
-the app will contain payment plugins?

should i use the native android studio and Xcode to develop it? or there is a better platform or tool ?

Comment: there is no best way. There is nothing best in programming.

Comment: Its ultimately opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I can think of is using React-Native.
It is lightweight and you use JS as the development language.
It uses Native ios and android components.
You will need an IDE for JS , Xcode and Android Studio.

Comment: Let me know if this was helpful and if you have any other questions

Comment: I think it all comes down to the payment plugins/sdk support fro native or JS and the developer knowledge in the required programming languages in the end.

Comment: This unfortunately is not the fact, but your opinion. Please avoid answering off-topic (opinion-based in this case) questions.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko unfortunately this question can only be answered with an opinion based answer.

Comment: thanks @Len_X .. but if a payment company like paypal .. has a plugin for native android .. can i use it with react??

Comment: @Len_X, this means it is opinion-based, which is off-topic: `Please avoid answering off-topic (opinion-based in this case) questions`

Comment: @AliZein React Native library that implements PayPal Checkout flow using purely native code. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paypal

Comment: @AliZein Let me know if this helped

Answer (score -1):

I used React-Native to Develop a native App for iOS and Android. And was really pleased because you can learn React really fast and there are tons of libraries for the Framework.

One  Benefits of react-native is that you can use an app for your Smartphone that allows you to scan a QR-Code which your react-native app creates so you can preview your app and see changes on your Smartphone in almost real time.

Another Framework that seems to be popular is the Ionic Framework that you might wanna look into.

Comment: How can you prove that it is best?

Comment: I edited my answer a bit to give you an idea what I like About it

Comment: still doesn't mean that it is best.